# Showing that $(\mathbb{R}^2,\boxplus,\boxdot)$ is not a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

I know that to be a linear space A1-A10 must be satisfied.
I said that this set and operations do not define a linear space over $\mathbb{R}$ because (A2) is not satisfied as
$$
(x_1,x_2)\boxplus(y_1,y_2) = (x_1+y_2, x_2+y_1)
$$
but
$$
(y_1,y_2)\boxplus(x_1,x_2) = (y_1+x_2,y_2+x_1)
$$
and $(x_1+y_2, x_2+y_1)$ does not equal $(y_1+x_2,y_2+x_1)$. Is this correct, and would it enough to answer the question?

Edit: with numbers an example would be $x = (1,2)$ and $y = (2,4)$.
$$
(1,2)\boxplus(2,4) = (5,4)
$$
but
$$
(2,4)\boxplus(1,2)= (4,5)
$$
and $(5,4)$ is not equal to $(4,5)$. Would this be enough to prove it's not a linear space?

Comment: Looks good to me!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to be very explicit to make things clear.

For example, we want to make sure $x_1 + y_2  \ne  y_1 + x_2$. We can pick $x_1 =y_1=x_2=0$ and $y_2=1$.

$$(0, 0)\boxplus (0,1) = (1,0) $$

but

$$(0, 1)\boxplus (0,0) = (0,1) $$

Edit:

I just see your edit, yes, it's ok. just that for some reason your second vector doesn't appear.

Comment: Thanks for your help